# Using cache in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to use caching in my code, but I keep getting the following error:

`ReferenceError: cache is not defined`.

I've tried looking in the documentation and on the internet as to what the error means, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Please share you code [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I played around with the cache service a bit.  Perhaps this will help.

```
function getMyData() {
  let cs=CacheService.getScriptCache();//select which cache
  let dt=JSON.parse(cs.get('mydata'));//parsing data back into object
  if(!dt) {//if no data in cache
    const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.targetid);
    const sh=ss.getSheetByName(gobj.globals.targetsh);
    const vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    cs.put('mydata',JSON.stringify(vs));//put data into cache
    dt=vs;//get data
    ss.toast('accessed cache');//just to let me know I accessed cache
  }
  return dt;
}

function displayMyData() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clearContents();
  let dt=getMyData();//gets data from original source or cache if it's availiable
  sh.getRange(1,1,dt.length,dt[0].length).setValues(dt);
}

function flushcache() {
  let cs=CacheService.getScriptCache();
  cs.removeAll(['mydata']);
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clearContents();
  ss.toast('flushed');
}
```

gobj.globals are just global variable I use

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the code below:

```js
const md5 = (key = '') => {
  const code = key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
  return Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, key)
    .map((char) => (char + 256).toString(16).slice(-2))
    .join('');
};

const getProperty = (key) => {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return scriptProperties.getProperty(md5(key));
};

const setProperty = (key, value) => {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty(md5(key), value);
};
```

Once this is implemented into your code, you can use the `getProperties` to retrieve any of the previously stored results. Like in the example below:

```js
const md5 = (key = '') => {
  const code = key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
  return Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, key)
    .map((char) => (char + 256).toString(16).slice(-2))
    .join('');
};

const getProperty = (key) => {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return scriptProperties.getProperty(md5(key));
};

const setProperty = (key, value) => {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty(md5(key), value);
};

const GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE = (origin, destination, mode = 'driving') => {

  const key = ['distance', origin, destination, mode].join(',');
  // Is result in the internal cache?
  const value = getProperty(key);
  // If yes, serve the cached result
  if (value !== null) return value;
  const { routes: [data] = [] } = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .setMode(mode)
    .getDirections();
  if (!data) {
    GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE;
  }
  const { legs: [{ distance: { text: distance } } = {}] = [] } = data;
  // Store the result in internal cache for future
  setProperty(key, distance);
  return distance;
};
```

In this example, `Properties` are used instead of `Cache` because it lets you store data indefinitely, while `Cache` is limited to 6 hours. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056018/store-google-api-results-in-cache-indefinitely/67056167#67056167) thread for further information on the examples.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) for `Properties`

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache) for `Cache`